# Regex to match lower case words but exclude certain words using Flex (The Fast Lexical Analyzer) 

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

i want to create a regex to match any lower case words but exclude 'return' and 'while', is it possible to do this? i don't want to solve like this:

```
return {/*nothing*/}
while {/*nothing*/}
[a-z]+ {/*some code*/}
```

Comment: Does this doc support your version of FLEX?  http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns

Comment: no, my version is flex 2.5.35

Comment: I looked at the documentation in the above comment and couldn't find way to do it except for what you described.  Why isn't your way acceptable?

Comment: yes, my solution looks like acceptable, but my real problem isn't exactly like this, i just want to parse c program source code using flex, i want to pick up snip code of function invocation, using like [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[ ]*[(].*[)], but this do match something like "while(1)", i just want exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want, but this might be helpful:

```
\b(?!(?:return|while)\b)[a-z]+
```

It matches

```
\b                      # A word break.
(?!(?:return|while)\b)  # This is a negative look around
                        # saying don't match if a return
                        # or while is matched followed by
                        # a word break.
[a-z]+                  # Match 1 or more lowercase letters.
```

Comment: Here is some doc I found for FLEX.  It doesn't mention word boundaries `\b` or negative lookaheads `(?!regex)`.  http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns

Comment: eh, i know what you mean, maybe your answer will work in some regex system, but flex don't support "!" and "\b"